# mongoose.find(req.query) is causing an error when I use methods to return data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When trying to fetch data from my get route, if I return just the response, the data gets fetched. But when I use mongoose methods i.e. mongoose.methods.summary = function() {...}.

Here is the code (this code goes to the catch block and always returns an error):

```
router.get('/callsheets', authenticate, (req, res) => {
  Callsheet.find(req.query)
    .then(callsheets => res.send(callsheets.summary()))
    .catch(err => res.json({ err }));
});
//the query is {creator: id}, which is passed from axios
//no errors in passing the query
```

Below is the code for my mongoose model:
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

```
const callSheetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  creator: { type: String, default: '' },
  published: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  sent: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  completed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  archived: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  client: { type: String, default: '' },
  project: { type: String, default: '' },
  production: { type: Array, default: [] },
  wardrobe: { type: Array, default: [] }
});

callSheetSchema.methods.summary = function() {
  const summary = {
    id: this._id,
    creator: this.creator,
    published: this.published,
    sent: this.sent,
    completed: this.completed,
    archived: this.archived,
    client: this.client,
    project: this.project,
    production: this.production,
    wardrobe: this.wardrobe
  };
  return summary;
};

export default mongoose.model('callsheet', callSheetSchema);
```

Again, if I just return `res.send(callsheet)`, the data is sent correctly. If I return `res.send(callsheet.summary())`, I hit the error block.

Any all help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Try res.json(callsheet.summary())

Comment: the err is an empty object (which is generated from the catch block). unfortunately res.json doesn't work either

Comment: If you do 'console.log(summary)' before 'return summary;' does it show up correctly?

Comment: Nothing is being console logged

Answer (score 0):

Try using virtual property http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals

```
callSheetSchema.virtual('summary').get(function () {
  const summary = {
    id: this._id,
    creator: this.creator,
    published: this.published,
    sent: this.sent,
    completed: this.completed,
    archived: this.archived,
    client: this.client,
    project: this.project,
    production: this.production,
    wardrobe: this.wardrobe
  };
  return summary;
});
```

And then use it as

```
router.get('/callsheets', authenticate, (req, res) => {
  Callsheet.find(req.query)
    .then(callsheets => res.send(callsheets.summary)) // <- not a method
    .catch(err => res.json({ err }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting this way 
`module.exports = callSheetSchema` instead of `export default callSheetSchema`

Comment: Ok, have you tried setting your Schema as `const Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
const callSheetSchema = new Schema({ }) ` instead of `mongoose.Schema({ })`?

Comment: No luck with the above suggestions

Answer (score 0):

On node I use module.export instead of export default

Comment: I've tried refactoring everything to es5, but it did not work

Comment: try it [https://scotch.io/courses/create-a-crud-app-with-node-and-mongodb/a-mongoose-model]